# How was the Anti-Pope chosen?

Tags: chilling-adventures-of-sabrina

When the Anti-Pope

> died

the Council had to appoint his replacement. They chose

> Faustus Blackwood.

I thought he was just the High Priest of some relatively unknown American church. Why was he, of all people, chosen to be the new Anti-Pope?

Comment: The conclave entered into the room.
Inside of it they sat, these cardinals of doom.
Their votes was unanimous.
The horror instantaneous.
Observe! Smoke from chimney - not white but red!
They say it was the day that God bled.
Nuns weeped, holy men cursed
As they looked up onto the balcony and saw...

Comment: Beelzebub the First.

Comment: Probably the same way they choose the real pope. Politics.

Comment: And wasn't he just the acting anti-pope, untill new is selected,

Comment: @Oni - True. I didn't think that detail was integral to the question.

Comment: This is a good question, I also found it remarkably strange. Another question is, wow come the council didn't investigate the anti-Pope's murder...